# how to set visible true and false for drop down list box using javascript in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddloption" runat="server" Visible="false">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Active" Value="Active"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="D-Active" Value="D-Active"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

function boxchange(dd)
{
  document.getElementById("<%= ddloption.ClientID%>").visibility = "visible";
}
```

ddloption is null, what i m getting...can you tell me how to work with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a `runat="server" visible="false"` asp control, it is not rendered in the html. Try something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="display: none;">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddloption" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Active" Value="Active"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="D-Active" Value="D-Active"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>


function boxchange(dd)
    {
          document.getElementById("wrapper").style.display = "block";
    }
```

Comment: hey i wrote the same in my code but it's not working and not giving any error...what can be the reason?

Comment: hmm.. not sure, it works in my sample page. You sure you didn't miss anything? removing the visible="false" from ddloption?

Answer (score 5):

To hide the dropdown

```
  document.getElementById("<%= ddloption.ClientID%>").Style.display='none';
```

To Show it again:

```
document.getElementById("<%= ddloption.ClientID%>").Style.display='';
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 function boxchange(dd)
 {
    var control = document.getElementById("<%= ddloption.ClientID %>");
    if (control != null)
       control.style.visibility = "visible";
 }
```

Nick is right, didn't even notice.