# how to set visibility for asp.net drop downlist in the javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have one dropdownlist in my asp.net web application. I want to set visibility for that dropdownlist in the Client side javascript such as visible=true or false. Can any one know solution for that means it will really appreciated.

Thank you..

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791759/how-to-set-visible-true-and-false-for-drop-down-list-box-using-javascript-in-asp

Comment: My Dropdownlist was there in the Content page. So can't able to give drop downlist inside the Div. So Can you pls tell me what can I do for that?

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery .show() and .hide() methods.  You will need to find the dropdownlist using the clientid value like so:

```
 $('#<%= myDropDown.ClientID %>').show() // shows dropdown
 $('#<%= myDropDown.ClientID %>').hide() // hides dropdown
```

Comment: Is it possible to give drop down id in that query such as ('ct100_content1_dropdown1') like that?

Comment: That is what the .ClientID property will return

Comment: But while I using that I got the error message like object expected. So Can you pls let me know what can I do for that?

Comment: @Kathirvel this sample is using jQuery. I will retag your question to include jQuery. Are you using jQuery in your page?

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample with Javascript alone:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function doToggle() {
            var ddl = document.getElementById("<%Response.Write(DropDownList1.ClientID.ToString()); %>");

            if (ddl.style.display == "none") {
                ddl.style.display = "block";
            }
            else {
                ddl.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <input id="Button1" onclick="doToggle();" type="button" value="Toggle" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Good luck!